# Do you automatically use past perfect when talking about like 10 years ago or is the simple past ok?

Tags: grammar, tense

Do you automatically use past perfect when talking about like 10 years ago or is the simple past ok?

For example:

> I had suffered from cancer when I was 2 years old.
>
> I suffered from cancer when I was 2 years old.

Do you use "had suffered" only when the simple past is used for a recent event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the past perfect to make it clear that some past event happened *before* another past event.

> I had suffered from cancer when I was 2 years old.

This means that you had cancer *before* you were 2 years old.

> I suffered from cancer when I was 2 years old.

This means that you had cancer *while* you were 2 years old.

Comment: In this instance, I suggest, the PAST PERFECT does NOT make it clear that the child had been cured of cancer by the age of 2, although some might infer it. Compare: I had suffered from acne when I was two years old. Few readers would assume that the acne had vanished by the time the child turned two. Rather that the child no longer suffered from acne.

Comment: Well, I guess you could say that the past perfect action *started* before the simple past action. With the first sentence, we don't know if the child was still suffering from cancer at 2 years old or not, just that the child had started suffering before the age of 2. I am not sure if there's an implication that the child still could have had the condition but no longer *suffered* (emotionally?) from it at age 2 (if this is what you're saying with the acne example).